# Can't refresh List with drag down Refresh (mSwipeRefreshLayout)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, list, swiperefreshlayout

I can't refresh my List (Network thread, so no UI Thread) on my UI Thread via a onRefresh Handler, this is the code I've tried:

```
    @Override
public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = AktuellesActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("gemeindeMuckendorf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    List<News> newsList = Utils.getNewsFromHTML(Utils.getHTML("www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/22-0-Aktuelle+Meldungen.html"));
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPrefs.edit();
                    edit.putString("aktuellesList", new ObjectSaver().saveString(newsList));
                    edit.commit();
                    final List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(News news : newsList)
                        headers.add(news.getHeader());
                    headers.add("Test");
                    AktuellesActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(AktuellesActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headers));
                            lv.invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 2000);
}
```

My I have a List that gets a String, puts it in a List and then I want it to get the List to replace the old List but apparently it won't work.. Doesn't do anything. I can't test it exactly but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work. Can someone help me out here?
Thanks!

Comment: html = Utils.getHTML("http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/22-0-Aktuelle+Meldungen.html");  Remove this out of uiThread.

Comment: @tinysunlight It's out now, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  refreshLayout = (PullRefreshLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new PullRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        String html = "";
                                    try { 
                                        html = Utils.getHTML("http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/22-0-Aktuelle+Meldungen.html");
                                        List<News> news = Utils.getNewsFromHTML(html);
                                        List<String> headers = new ArrayList();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < news.size(); i++)
                                            headers.add(news.get(i).getHeader());
                                        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(AktuellesActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headers));
                                        lv.invalidate(); 
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } 
                                        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is just another method for writing, isn't it? The circle is spinning for me, it just doesn't update the list...

Comment: Have checked the data is coming from that Url ?

Comment: What i have posted is the proper way of refreshing , you have to put your logic   inside public void run()  method to get what you want after refresh